# Mysql slave alwayws shows "Slave_IO_Running: Connecting，Last_IO_Errno: 2061", then change to 1129

Tags: mysql

I am configuring mysql master and slave. I confirm when I ran "change master to" command, the following settings are correct and consistent to the values on master side:

```
MASTER_HOST
MASTER_USER
MASTER_PASSWORD
MASTER_LOG_FILE
MASTER_LOG_POS
```

Now, on slave side, it shows as below:

```
mysql> show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
              Master_Host: 172.16.0.5
              Master_User: repl_1
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: master-bin.000003
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 155
           Relay_Log_File: slave-relay-bin.000001
            Relay_Log_Pos: 4
    Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000003
         Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB: myslave
      Replicate_Ignore_DB:
       Replicate_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Ignore_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error:
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 155
          Relay_Log_Space: 155
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File:
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File:
       Master_SSL_CA_Path:
          Master_SSL_Cert:
        Master_SSL_Cipher:
           Master_SSL_Key:
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
   Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 2061
            Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'repl_1@172.16.0.5:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 2
```

On master side:

```
mysql> show master status;
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File              | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| master-bin.000003 |      155 | myslave      | mysql            |                   |
+-------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But slave is always unable to connect master, and reports errors in /var/log/mysql/error.log as below:

```
2018-11-11T13:51:34.706080Z 22 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl_1@172.16.0.5:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1, Error_code: MY-002061
2018-11-11T13:52:34.708404Z 22 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl_1@172.16.0.5:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 2, Error_code: MY-002061
2018-11-11T13:53:34.710593Z 22 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl_1@172.16.0.5:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 3, Error_code: MY-002061
2018-11-11T13:54:34.713441Z 22 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl_1@172.16.0.5:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 4, Error_code: MY-002061
2018-11-11T13:55:34.716135Z 22 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl_1@172.16.0.5:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 5, Error_code: MY-002061
```

and, after 99 times retires, error_code changes to MY-001129:

```
2018-11-11T11:24:02.802629Z 11 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl_1@172.16.0.5:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 99, Error_code: MY-002061
2018-11-11T11:25:02.804339Z 11 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl_1@172.16.0.5:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 100, Error_code: MY-001129
2018-11-11T11:26:02.806537Z 11 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl_1@172.16.0.5:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 101, Error_code: MY-001129
```

On master side, /var/log/mysql/error.log shows nothing. The tcpdump on master side shows that it(172.16.0.5) has received the login request from slave(172.16.0.4) with user "repl_1". But it replies with an "auth switch request". Then the slave initiated termination of connection with "[FIN, ACK]".
I am pretty sure the password of "repl_1" was the same when I created the user on master, and when I executed "change master to ....MASTER_PASSWORD...".
[tcpdump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxgPf.png)

Comment: I know the format of my text is too bad. But I am trying to re-format it but because I am a newcomer I didn't find how to format those content like the output of commands and the logs. I really thanks Samir for formatting it.

Comment: I'm convinced it has to do something with encrypted connections. Read the "Important" section in the last comment here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89959